# How do I apply custom font at custom UIbutton with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have added custom font in to my application and applied it custom UIButton class like below.

```
import UIKit

class MainButton: UIButton {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.tintColor = .black
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Myfont", size: 14)
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. And I tried another way like below.

```
import UIKit

class MainButton: UIButton {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.tintColor = .black
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Myfont", size: 14)
    }
}
```

and

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyBtn: MainButton!
MyBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Myfont", size: 14)
```

The custom font was applied at first.
But when I clicked the button, its font changed to system font.
And I tried like this.

```
@IBOutlet var MyBtn: MainButton!
MyBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Myfont", size: 14)
```

But the result was same.
So, how do I apply custom font at custom UIButton?

Comment: your code worked for me.
Maybe you forgot to assign the `MainButton` class in the identity inspector of the `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

step 1 : select you button

step 2 : Navigate to Identity Inspector

step 3 : assign a `MainButton` class to `UIButton`

step 4 : then create `IBOutlet` of `UIButton`

[image]